# Sequelize v5 underscored option is not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I am using node.js with sequelize and typescript on vs code.

Recently migrated to sequelize v5 for using typescript.

So I removed "underscoredAll" option because it is no more supported on sequelize v5.

But problem is here.

My MySQL table definition is still works. I already defined all columns using underscore and sequelize loaded data well.

I've been using this system for eight months, before upgrade to sequelize v5.

[image]

Please check this image, "Auth" is instance of sequelize model.

"ChannelId" is a foreignKey and "createdAt" is timestamp, which created by sequelize.

Yes, Instance's member is not underscored field.

That fields still camelCased.

I already tried set underscored option to each model init function option.

Nevertheless, It didn't work.

What can I do for this problem T.T

Please Help Me... I want to go home...

```js
const database = new Sequelize('db_name', 'username', 'pwd', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    dialectOptions: {
        connectTimeout: 30000
    },
    define: {
        underscored: true,
        // underscoredAll: true /* removed on v5 */
    },
    pool: {
        max: 100,
        idle: 30000,
        acquire: 60000,
    },
    logging: false
});
```